# 1D diffusion equation with boundary condition

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

Suppose we have the diffusion equation defined by $$u_t(x,t) = \Delta_x u(x,t) \ \ \ \  \text{in}\ \ (0,L)\times (0,T)$$
with the boundary condition
$$u(0,t)=f(t)$$
$$u(L,t)=g(t)$$
and the initial condition
$$u(x,0)=c$$
where $c>0$ is a constant.
Let us assume that all the functions here are sufficiently smooth and suppose $f$ and $g$ are decreasing. Then is it true that all the values at the interior points are also decreasing with time? It seems physically reasonable but I cannot see how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, unless there are additional assumptions.

Suppose $f(0) = g(0) = 1$ and $c = 1/2$. Then at interior points the solution will first increase and then decrease.

A sufficient condition for $u$ to be decreasing in $t$ everywhere is that $c \ge \max\{f(0), g(0)\}$. Proof if $f$ and $g$ are smooth: Consider $v = \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$ and apply the maximum principle to ahow that $v \le 0$ everywhere. Proof in the general case: Approximation.